# Error "Trying to re-register the builtin cmap 'cubehelix' when trying to import the python module "yt"

Tags: python, pip, yt

I installed the Python package `yt` simply through `pip install yt`. When I tried to import it, it returns the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from yt.fields.api import \
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\fields\api.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import angular_momentum
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\fields\angular_momentum.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .vector_operations import \
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\fields\vector_operations.py", line 32, in <module>
    from yt.geometry.geometry_handler import \
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\geometry\geometry_handler.py", line 29, in <module>
    from yt.utilities.parallel_tools.parallel_analysis_interface import \
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\utilities\parallel_tools\parallel_analysis_interface.py", line 30, in <module>
    from yt.data_objects.image_array import ImageArray
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\data_objects\image_array.py", line 18, in <module>
    from yt.visualization.image_writer import write_bitmap, write_image
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\visualization\image_writer.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .color_maps import mcm
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\visualization\color_maps.py", line 164, in <module>
    add_colormap("cubehelix", _cubehelix_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt\visualization\color_maps.py", line 52, in add_colormap
    mcm.register_cmap(name, yt_colormaps[name])
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 149, in register_cmap
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Trying to re-register the builtin cmap 'cubehelix'.
```

I have tried to search online for solutions but it seems that almost nobody has ever addressed the same issue. I have tried to force reinstall it by `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall yt` but still the same error message occurred. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled your error and found https://mail.python.org/archives/list/yt-users@python.org/message/5C2ZTKNETGVY24QY2G6ED33CGFUPRQSW/ from a couple of months ago, which leads to https://github.com/yt-project/yt/pull/3149.

It looks like the workaround could be to downgrade Matplotlib to a version less than 3.4.0.